# siunitx : How to align \qty value numbers in tables

Tags: tables, align, siunitx, units, makecell

I would like to make a table with values followed by its units, in which the numbers of the values are aligned according to the "rules" of the `siunitx`-package. I can do this with two columns (one for the values in S and one for the units in l), but I would like to have them in one column.

The command for values and units in the new v3 version of `siunitx`-package is:
`\qty[⟨options⟩]{⟨number⟩}{⟨unit⟩}`

Here follows my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{makecell}% forced line break in cell of tabular
\usepackage{siunitx}% SI units & number alignment in table

%-----------------------------------------------------------%
%                       SI UNITX

\sisetup{%
    mode=math,% math, match or text
    propagate-math-font=true,%
    text-series-to-math, text-family-to-math,%
%
    unit-optional-argument=true, free-standing-units=true,% units use outside siunitx
    use-xspace=true, space-before-unit=true,% space before units
    quantity-product=\;,% hspace number-unit
    exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot},%
    per-mode=fraction, sticky-per,% fraction symbol
% Uncertainty & exponent
    bracket-ambiguous-numbers=false,%
    separate-uncertainty, uncertainty-mode=separate, separate-uncertainty-units=single,% ± sign for (#)
    table-align-uncertainty=true,%
    table-align-exponent=true,%
% Alignment
    table-alignment-mode=format,%
    table-number-alignment=center,% number cells in S column
    table-text-alignment=center,% text only cells in S column
    tight-spacing=false}%

%-----------------------------------------------------------%
%                       MAKECELL SETTINGS

\makegapedcells% vsep cells
\setcellgapes{0pt}% extra vsep of rows

    \renewcommand\cellset{%
        \def\arraystretch{1.0}% vspace between rows, height row, line spacing
        \setcellgapes{0pt}%
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% hsep columns (text-border)
        \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}% vsep above cell
        }%
        
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
%                       COLUMNS
%   Text-style math
    \newcolumntype{u}[1]% units
        { @{\,} >{$\textstyle} #1 <{$} }%

%   Siunitx
    \newcolumntype{J}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}%
    \newcolumntype{U}[1]{S[table-format=#1,%
        table-align-uncertainty=false,%
        table-align-exponent=false]}

%-----------------------------------------------------------%
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

%---------%
\section{Siunits Tabular Uncertainty}%

Referencing tables automatically by \ref{tab:uncertain}.\par

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{A wide math mode tabular table with si unit columns of uncertainty}%
        \label{tab:uncertain}
  \begin{tabular}%
        { U{-1.3(2)e2} u{l} | 
          J{-1.3(2)e2} | 
          J{+1.3(2)e2} u{l} }
    \toprule
        {U \{-1.3(2)e2\}}                           & {u \{l\}} &
        {J \{-1.3(2)e2\}}                           &
        {J \{+1.3(2)e2\}}                           & {u \{l\}} \\
    \midrule
        1.1e19                                      & \unit{\coulomb \per \V} &
        \qty{-0.497(17)}{\A \per \V}                &
        2.6e21                                      & \unit{\J \per \coulomb} \\
        9.6(2)e24                                   & \unit{\m\kg \per \square\s} &
        \qty{-2.17(39)e22}{\s\kg \per \square\m}    &
        -2.17(39)e22                                & \unit{\N \per \square\m} \\
        -0.224(41)                                  & \unit{\siemens} &
        \qty{2.3(4)}{\kg}                           &
        +-6.2(2)                                    & \psi \\
        \qty{-0.224(41)}{\N \per \square\m}         & & 
        \qty{2.890(4)}{\s\kg \per \square\m}        &
        \qty{2.890(4)}{\s\kg \per \square\m}        & \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It seems like the `\qty` command makes the number value into a text number, see last row & 2nd column in the pictures below how its value is influenced by the `table-text-alignment` option and not the `table-number-alignment` option:

`\sisetup{table-text-alignment=center}`:
[image: table-text-alignment=center]

`\sisetup{table-text-alignment=left}` without makecell settings:
[image: table-text-alignment=left]

Furtermore, I have to use the `makecell`-package for other tables. However, the `table-text-alignment=left` option with makecell settings results in this same text centering of `\qty`:

`\sisetup{table-text-alignment=left}` with `makecell` settings:
[image: left and makecell]

Is there a way to make value+unit columns with `siunitx` alignment "rules" and using the `makecell`-package?

Comment: I've ben looking at this, but I'm not sure exactly what input you really want: for example, your demos have some units in with the value and some separately. Also, you will need to know the widest unit to get alignment to work if it's in the same column as the value: that's probably going to be tricky.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! Preferably I would want to make a table with numerical values and their units in one column, where the numbers are aligned according to the siunitx "rules". So the 3rd column in my example table with \qty{}{}, where the numbers should be aligned on their uncertainty sign/decimal point/exponent. The table contains my own attempts to solve the problem with an extra column for the units, but I prefer to have the value+unit in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would not recommend it, one could take the content of the cell, split it into the `\qty`, the first argument and the second argument, then construct the cell manually using `\tablenum`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}


\sisetup{%
    propagate-math-font=true,%
    text-series-to-math, text-family-to-math,%
%
    quantity-product=\;,% hspace number-unit
    exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot},%
    per-mode=fraction, sticky-per,% fraction symbol
% Uncertainty & exponent
    bracket-ambiguous-numbers=false,%
    uncertainty-mode=separate,
  }

\newcolumntype{J}[1]
  {>{\sisetup{table-format = {#1}}\collectcell\mycolumn}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{U}[1]
    {>{\sisetup{table-format = {#1},table-align-uncertainty=false,%
 table-align-exponent=false}\collectcell\mycolumn}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand\mycolumn[1]{
  \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} \qty
    { \mycolumnaux#1\stop }
    {
      \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} { { \use:n #1 } }
        {#1}
        { \tablenum {#1} }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycolumnaux{}
\long\def\mycolumnaux #1\qty#2#3\stop{%
  \tablenum{#2}%
  \llap{\;\unit{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Siunits Tabular Uncertainty}%

Referencing tables automatically by \ref{tab:uncertain}.\par

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{A wide math mode tabular table with si unit columns of uncertainty}%
        \label{tab:uncertain}
  \begin{tabular}%
        { 
          @{}
          U{-1.3(2)e2{\;\unit{\m\kg \per \square\s}}} | 
          J{-1.3(2)e2{\;\unit{\s\kg \per \square\m}}} | 
          J{+1.3(2)e2{\;\unit{\s\kg \per \square\m}}}
          @{}
        }
    \toprule
        {U \{-1.3(2)e2\}}                           & 
        {J \{-1.3(2)e2\}}                           &
        {J \{+1.3(2)e2\}}                           \\
    \midrule
        \qty{1.1e19}{\coulomb \per \V}              &
        \qty{-0.497(17)}{\A \per \V}                &
        \qty{2.6e21}{\J \per \coulomb}              \\
        \qty{9.6(2)e24}{\m\kg \per \square\s}       &
        \qty{-2.17(39)e22}{\s\kg \per \square\m}    &
        \qty{-2.17(39)e22}{\N \per \square\m}       \\
        \qty{-0.224(41)}{\siemens}                  &
        \qty{2.3(4)}{\kg}                           &
        \qty{+-6.2(2)}{\psi}                        \\
        \qty{-0.224(41)}{\N \per \square\m}         & 
        \qty{2.890(4)}{\s\kg \per \square\m}        &
        \qty{2.890(4)}{\s\kg \per \square\m}        \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have used `\llap` to make the printed unit have 'no width', as `\tablenum` saves space based on the `table-format`. (If we don't allow for the unit text in the format, we loose control of alignment.)

I've tested cell content by checking:

- If they start with `\qty` (the `\tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nTF` test)
- If they are wrapped in braces (the `\str_if_eq:eeTF` test)
- Otherwise, they are to be used as is

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my problem perfectly! Have a nice day!