# \qty alignment value in IEEEtran tables

Tags: tables, siunitx, ieeetran

So with the new version of `siunitx` there is this woderful command called `\qty{}{}`, yet in my table, I would like to have the numerical value aligned on the decimal point (the `g_m` coloumn).

The quick woraround would be to separate this last coloumn into two, the first ona as an `S` -type, only with numerical value, then the last one an usual `l` -type with the unit using the `\unit{}` command.

But I bet there is a way, tweaking some setting in the table, to make `\qty{}{}` work the way I need.

The thing is I'm not familiar with the IEEE format yet. And [this answer about \qty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630539/siunitx-how-to-align-qty-value-numbers-in-tables) just span my table in an ugly way (still using the full code, preamble and so on, from my prevoius question [my prevoius question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683103/tabular-and-si-unit-comand-ua-giving-a-weird-t) about `siunitx`).

```
\begin{table}[!th]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{Parameters of Mn\textsubscript{3} and Mn\textsubscript{4}}
    \label{tab:CM-1}
    \sisetup{
        table-alignment-mode = marker,        % changed from FORMAT
        table-number-alignment = center,
        table-figures-integer = 1,
        table-figures-decimal = 4,
    }
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S}}
        \toprule
        {Transistor}    & {W/L} & {W}   & {L}   & {g\textsubscript{m}}  \\
        \midrule
         Mn\textsubscript{3}    & \num{2.696}   & \qty{8.7}{\um}    & \qty{1}{\um}  & \qty{200}{\micro S}   \\
         Mn\textsubscript{4}    & \num{2.899}   & \qty{2.9}{\um}    & \qty{1}{\um}  & \qty{66.7}{\micro S}  \\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

That gives the following output,
[image: gm not decimal aligned]

Comment: Firstly, please always provide a full but minimal example and not a sniplet like this. Secondly, it is more traditional to add the unit as a part of the header. Then the `S` column can do its thing with the amount part. Here I don't think it is supported for `S` to look inside `\num` or `\qty`.

Comment: Sorry, I always think that's a common use, I tend to forget it is highly costumizable using so many packages and they may interfere one with the other, or there can be a missing one....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not repeat the unit in every cell, but write it in the header in parentheses.

I recommend using `newtx` with `IEEEtran` so you get math symbols compatible with Times. A further bit has to be added, since the LaTeX kernel doesn't (yet) know about the full set of TS1 symbols in `newtx`.

Now you can get precise alignment of the figures by specifying the format for each column.

There is the abbreviation `\um` for `\micro\meter`, but there isn't one for the siemens, better spelling it out and not mixing `\micro S`.

I guess that the headers in the last four columns should be in math mode.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

% newtx has the full set
\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{ntxtlf}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering

\caption{Parameters of Mn\textsubscript{3} and Mn\textsubscript{4}}
\label{tab:CM-1}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=3.1]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Transistor & {$W/L$} & {$W$} & {$L$} & {$g_{m}$} \\
& & {(\unit{\um})} & {(\unit{\um})} & {(\unit{\micro\siemens})} \\
\midrule
Mn\textsubscript{3} & 2.696 & 8.7 & 1 & 200   \\
Mn\textsubscript{4} & 2.899 & 2.9 & 1 &  66.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @egreg, I lazyly just copied and did some light modification to fit my needs, of the first table in the document, a tabular environment `{llSl}` that had all the specification for the project, with many different units, put in the las coloumn. So to look consistently, I used the prefix, but not the unit `\siemens`. If it's stupid and it works, .....

Answer (score 6):

Each cell under the column type `S` is parsed by `siunitx`, which expects numbers. Otherwise, you will get errors.

If you really want units next to every number in the table, one way is to physically add `\unit{}` after each quantity. It can be done in column definition. However because of `S`, extra space occupied by units also has to be "added". The code below produces an output, which I believe is something you would expect

[image]

and the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!th]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{Parameters of Mn\textsubscript{3} and Mn\textsubscript{4}}
    \label{tab:CM-11}
    \sisetup{
        table-alignment-mode = marker,        % changed from FORMAT
        table-number-alignment = center,
        table-figures-integer = 1,
        table-figures-decimal = 4,
        % table-align-text-after = false,     % units stick to quantities 
    }
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            l
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=1.1{\,\unit{\micro\metre}}]<{\,\unit{\micro\metre}}
            S[table-format=1.0{\,\unit{\micro\metre}}]<{\,\unit{\micro\metre}}
            S[table-format=3.1{\,\unit{\micro\siemens}}]<{\,\unit{\micro\siemens}}
        }
        \toprule
        Transistor
        & {W/L}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{W}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{L}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g\textsubscript{m}} \\
        \midrule
         Mn\textsubscript{3} & 2.696 & 8.7 & 1 & 200 \\
         Mn\textsubscript{4} & 2.899 & 2.9 & 1 & 66.7 \\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

IMO you should avoid repeated information in cells. Hence, I would move units to the corresponding headers and leave only numbers in the body. I see this as a clearer output

[image]

and the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!th]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{Parameters of Mn\textsubscript{3} and Mn\textsubscript{4}}
    \label{tab:CM-1}
    \sisetup{
        table-alignment-mode = marker,        % changed from FORMAT
        table-number-alignment = center,
        table-figures-integer = 1,
        table-figures-decimal = 4,
    }
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=1.1] S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=3.1]}
        \toprule
        {Transistor} & {W/L} & {W} & {L} & {g\textsubscript{m}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5}
                     & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\unit{\micro\metre})} & {(\unit{\micro\siemens})} \\
        \midrule
         Mn\textsubscript{3} & 2.696 & 8.7 & 1 & 200 \\
         Mn\textsubscript{4} & 2.899 & 2.9 & 1 & 66.7 \\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Celdor,  that's exactly the format  I was looking for